# How to make css grid responsive in small screen

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to create a responsive magazine style post-blocks using css grid. But In small screen, how can I make them responsive ? I want that, in small screen div `1` will be 100% width/block. Div `2 and 3` will be 50% and will be inline (in same line). Div `4` Will be 100% same as `div 1` Div `5 and 6` will be 50% and will be inline, same as `2 and 3` (in same line).

How can I do it ?

Heres My Code:

```css
.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-gap: 10px;
}
.div{
background: teal;
padding: 12px;
}
.div:nth-child(1) { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; }
.div:nth-child(2) { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.div:nth-child(3) { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }
.div:nth-child(4) { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div:nth-child(5) { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4; }
.div:nth-child(6) { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="div">1</div>
<div class="div">2</div>
<div class="div">3</div>
<div class="div">4</div>
<div class="div">5</div>
<div class="div">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use media queries with `@media` to apply different styles for different sizes. Then instead of hardcoding the grid with `grid-area` you should simply use `span` to apply different length for resolutions:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.div {
  background: teal;
  padding: 12px;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 719px) {
    .div {
      grid-column: span 2;
    }
    
    .div:nth-child(3n + 1) {
      grid-column: span 4;
    }  
}



@media only screen
  and (min-width: 720px) {
    .div {
      grid-column: span 1;
    }
    
    .div:nth-child(4n + 1) {
      grid-column: span 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div">1</div>
  <div class="div">2</div>
  <div class="div">3</div>
  <div class="div">4</div>
  <div class="div">5</div>
  <div class="div">6</div>
</div>
```